# How to get containers details like workload or image etc for GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I wanted to get List of containers and their details running on GCP Kubernets, 
From API page https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/container/v1/
We could get Cluster and Node details, but I'm looking for more granular levels like Pods and Container.

Is there any way to get those.

Comment: Do you mean without using kubectl? only REST API?

Comment: Do you mean without using kubectl? only REST API?

Answer (score 0):

Pod and container details are accessible through the kubernetes API, not using the Google Cloud SDK.

Unfortunately, this means getting that information on a per cluster basis.

Alternatively, the Cloud Console can be used by going to Kubernetes Engine > Workloads which will list all replica sets and individual pods (if not controlled by a replicaset).

You might be able to configure Stackdriver Monitoring to create a group consisting of all the pod and container resources in use in the project and then use the [Monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.groups.members/list) to call on that group, but I haven't tested that.